# no form action performed after clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php

So to start with a little bit of code:

JS:

```
  function showTest(nrOdp) {

    if (nrOdp < arrLen - 1) {
        div.innerHTML = "<form action='check.php' method='post'><div class='card-panel col s12 black-text'><p>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].pytanie + "</p></div> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_a + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_b + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_d + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_c + "</span> </p> </div> </label><div class='col s6'><input class='btn center' type='submit' onclick='showTest(" + (nrOdp + 1) + ")' value='Następne'></div></form>";
    } else if (nrOdp <= arrLen - 1) {
        div.innerHTML = "<form action='check.ph' method='post'><div class='card-panel col s12 black-text'><p>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].pytanie + "</p></div> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_a + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_b + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_d + "</span> </p> </div> </label> <label> <div class='card-panel col s6'> <p> <input class='with-gap' name='odp' type='radio'/> <span>" + testName.pytania[nrOdp].odpowiedz_c + "</span> </p> </div> </label><div class='col s6'><input type='submit' class='btn center' onclick='timerState(false)' value='Zakończ'></div></form>";
    }
}
```

and now what I mean,
the script displays the first elements where is the "Następne" where the php code is given, but nothing happens after clicking this button, while when the last element is displayed where it is "Zakończ", the php code is already running, and I want to make it every time when I click the "Następne" button the php code was executed

Comment: `mathod='post'` -> `method='post'`?

Comment: no, that's not it

Comment: action='check.ph' -> form action='check.php' ?

Comment: That's not it :(

Comment: Maybe your `onClick` handlers `showTest` and `timerState` has a preventDefault call on the event?

Comment: the problem is where at first onclick  because when I remove `onclick='showTest(" + (nrOdp + 1) + ")'` it all works well, but I need to call this function to switch to next questions